# Comparison of two-dimensional data structures - simplify and faster?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

How can the following code be simplified and made faster?

This is a comparison of two-dimensional data structures. Several folders, each folder contains files, compared with other folders.

```
ArrayList<FolderGroup> userFolders = CommonFunctions.getUserFolders();
if (!userFolders.isEmpty()) {
    for (FolderGroup userFoldersGroup : userFolders) {
        for (FolderGroup publicFoldersGroup : publicGroupsList) {
            if (userFoldersGroup.getName().equals(publicFoldersGroup.getName())) {
                for (File publicFile : publicFoldersGroup.getFiles()) {
                    for (File userFile : userFoldersGroup.getFiles()) {
                        if (publicFile.contains(userFile)) {
                            publicFile.setIsDownloaded(true);
                            userFoldersGroup.setDownloadedCount();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What do you want to check\find?

Comment: Why is this code inadequate? Have you used a profiler?

Comment: I compare files in folders. Checks whether the same files in two different folders. At the same time I have  2 arrays of folders.

Comment: @durron597 It is enough, but I want a more elegant solution.

Comment: Why do you want a more elegant solution? Is there an actual performance problem? Is it for aesthetics? Do you find the nested loops unmaintainable in some way? What I'm really trying to say is, it's difficult to help you improve the code unless you give us a **specific problem to solve**.

Comment: @durron597 The case of aesthetics. Performance I have not tested.

Answer (score 0):

The out-most `if` is futile, as the out-most loop will terminate immediately without iterating when `userFolders` is empty, anyway.

Other than that, I don't think the overall complexity can be reduced. You can however make the code much easier to understand by extracting methods with meaningful names.

What you can do to get more speed is to use data structures that allow you to use fewer nested loops. For example, you'd only need to iterate over one of the folder group collections if you could query the other folder group collection by folder group name. The standard library comes with some collection classes that allow such queries and that implement [the `Map` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) ([Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)).